# Next.js 14 how to change route from app to pages || get error 404

Tags: next.js

I use this dashboard starter: `https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/admin-dashboard-tailwind-postgres-react-nextjs`

Next.js 14

I need add server side fetching, because is not possible use this directly in app directory. I try create directory pages and here I move routes.

But everytime I get 404 not found (in app working correct).

Here is my tsconfig.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Can anyone help me? I try  research  information but I not see how to resolve.

I remove all from app directory and leave only layout.tsx, rest I move to pages directory outside app.

I try also rename from page.tsx to index.tsx